# Alternative definition for Hausdorff measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

The definition of the Hausdorff measure $H_s(S)$ of a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\lim_{\delta\to 0} H_s^\delta(S)$ (where $H_s^\delta(S)$ is the infimum of all $\sum_n diam(U_n)^s$ where $(U_n)$ is an countable open covering of $S$ such that $diam(U_n)<\delta$ for all $n$.

My question is the following :

Is there a reason as to why we restrict the diameter of the $U_n$ by a number $\delta$ and then take the limit when $\delta\to 0$ ?

In other words, couldn't we just define a measure $H'_s(S)$ by saying that 
$H'_s(S)$ is the infimum of all $\sum_n diam(U_n)^s$ where $(U_n)$ is a countable open covering of $S$ ?

Would that give a measure, and would that give something interesting?

Comment: For $H_s'$, I *think* that $H_{1/2}'([0,1])=1$ but $H_{1/2}'([0,1/2])=H_{1/2}'[1/2,1]=1/\sqrt{2}$. Thus, $H_{1/2}'([0,1])\neq H_{1/2}'([0,1/2])+H_{1/2}'([1/2,1])$ so that $H_s'$ is not a measure, at least not on the Borel sets.

Comment: What you define is usually denoted by $\mathcal{H}^s_\infty$ (in your notation $H^\infty_s$). It isn't a good measurement of a set because for example *any* set contained in a ball $B(0,\frac12)$ will have $\mathcal{H}^s_\infty$ measure $\leq 1$, no matter what $s$ (take the cover given by the ball!). The $\mathcal{H}^s$ Hausdorff measure instead tries to capture the "$s$-dimensional" measure of a set. For instance $\mathcal{H}^1(B)=\infty$ if $B$ is a ball in $\mathbb R^2$. To capture this behaviour you must look at smaller and smaller scales, i.e. consider $\delta\to 0$.